# Rho and Omega meson mixing

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, mesons

I am new to particle physics. So this might seem to be a trivial question.

I read about $\omega$ and $\phi$ meson states being written in terms of octet and singlet state.

In the same way, can $\rho$ and $\omega$ states interfere and how can the mixing angle be calculated?

I have this question since $\rho$ and $\phi$ have isospin $1$ and $0$ respectively. So can we apply the same procedure for $\rho$ and $\omega$ states as for $\phi$ and $\omega$ states?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For two particles to interfere, you need them to have similar quantum numbers. For example, a $\rho^+$ could not interfere with the neutral $\phi$ or $\omega$, since the respective transition would violate charge.

What about the $\rho^0 =(u\bar{u}-d\bar{d})/\sqrt{2}$? It sure has a similar mass to the   $ \omega=(u\bar{u}+d\bar{d})/\sqrt{2} $, since these two particles are composed of the same *u,d* quarks, in different arrangements, and it does not violate charge. But, as you point out, they are isotriplet and isosinglet respectively, so a transition between them would entail violation of isospin (and, related, G-parity), which is a pretty good symmetry in QCD/low-energy-physics.

Same, a fortiori, for the $\phi$.

At this point, you might go back to SU(3) singlet-octet mixing, and wonder how *these states* mix, since they violate (break) SU(3). That's just it: ***if*** the strange quark were as light as the *u,d*, SU(3) would be as good a symmetry as isospin, and, ipso facto, you would not have ideal $\omega-\phi$ mixing! But the strange quark is big-time heavier: look at the mass of the $\phi=s\bar{s}$, 240MeV bigger than that of the $\omega$.
This is close to the QCD scale and so not ignorable.

Conversely, the $\phi$ cannot go to 3 virtual gluons and hence the $ \omega=(u\bar{u}+d\bar{d})/\sqrt{2} $ because of "Zweig's rule": a magic protection of the $s\bar{s}$ against annihilating into gluons. Absent that protection, the transition would happen, and $\omega \leftrightarrow\phi$   would occur, thereby restoring a perfect SU(3), namely the unmixed states $ \phi_0=(u\bar{u}+d\bar{d}+s\bar{s})/\sqrt{3} $ and $ \phi_8=(u\bar{u}+d\bar{d}-2s{s})/\sqrt{6} $ .

[image]

So, for the vector octet, you might as well look at the horizontals of the "stop sign" diagram and de-emphasize U and V spin... The different *s* masses have compromised the entire structure and resulted to ideal mixing--ideal breaking, that is!

---

*Edit in response to question*

Calculating the mixing theoretically from first principles might be hard. One may just *fit* the experimental masses to determine the experimental value of the mixing angle for 
$$
\omega=\phi_0 \cos \theta + \phi_8 \sin \theta \\
\phi=\phi_0 \sin \theta - \phi_8 \cos \theta ~.
$$

Whereas ideal mixing (above) is 35⁰= arcsin 1/√3, the phenomenological fit is pretty close, 40⁰. It comes from the Gell-Mann-Okubo mass formula determined octet mass $m_8=930$MeV, $m_\omega=783$MeV, and $m_\phi=1019$MeV, plugged into 
$$
\tan ^2 \theta= \frac{m^2_\phi  - m^2_8 }{m^2_8 -m^2_\omega} ~~.
$$

The angle decreases to 38⁰, virtually ideal mixing, if one uses masses instead of their squares in the above formula, which now appears more sensible given the fact vector mesons are *not* chiral symmetry goldstons (only the pseudo scalar mesons are).